# New covariance and mean in gaussian process regression

Tags: gaussian-process

I'm trying to understand making predictions from a Gaussian Process with noise free observations. For reference I'm using GPML by Rasmussen and Williams.

**Setup:** Given that $f \sim \mathcal{GP}(\mathbf{0},k(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}'))$, training set $X$ and test set $X_*$ consisting of $N$ and $N_*$ elements each. Let
$$
\mathbf{f} = [f(x_1),...,f(x_N)]^T \text{ and } \mathbf{f}_* = [f(x_1),...,f(x_{N_*})]^T.
$$
From what I understand our goal is to predict $\mathbf{f}_*$, and we do this by first considering the joint distribution of training and test outputs,
$$
[\mathbf{f}, \mathbf{f}_*]^T \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0},\Sigma),
$$
where
$$
 \Sigma = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 K(X,X) & K(X,X_*) \\
 K(X,X_*)^T & K(X_*,X_*)
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 K_{XX} & K_* \\ 
 K_*^T & K_{**}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So what we do to make predictions is condition the gaussian prior based on our data to yield
$$
 \mathbf{f}_* | X_*, D, \mathbf{f} \sim \mathcal{N}(\overline{m}(\mathbf{x}),\overline{k}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}') ),
$$
where
$$
\overline{m}(\mathbf{x}) = K_*^TK^{-1}\mathbf{f} \\
  \overline{k}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}')  = K_{**} - K_*^TK^{-1}K_*.
$$
My question is what are these new covariance and mean terms? In GPML they write

> In fact, eq. (2.23) is the mean function and eq. (2.24) the covariance function of the (Gaussian) posterior process.

I suppose my question is how do these define *functions*? I get that we form the initial covariance matrix $\Sigma$ by evaluating the kernel function at training, test, and training-test points, but from what I understand $\overline{k}$ is just an $N_* \times N_*$ matrix, so if it means that it's just a new covariance matrix that makes sense, but I don't see how it can be specifying a *new kernel function* for the posterior GP.

I'm new to the material so any help is appreciated, let me know if I can clarify any of my confusions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you tell me X_* then I can use those formulas to tell you the corresponding $\overline{m}$ and $\overline{k}$-that's all they mean.

Comment: So you get test points $X_*$, then the posterior prediction $\overline{m}(\mathbf{x})$ is some $N^* \times 1$ vector; which when you plot all the points "looks like" a continuous function (if the feature vectors are 1d)? Am I understanding it properly @MikeHawk?